Customizations to a keymap apply to all other keymaps / modifications made to one keymap affect all keymaps globally
In Blender 4.2 LTS, when one keymap configuration file is edited all the other ones reflect the change. For example, here are the four I have:

I make a single hotkey change to the "giuliop Keymap":

The same change propagates to all the other Keymap configuration files, for example, the original "Blender" (which I did not touch at all):

Why is this so? Would it be possible to have completely separate Keymap files?
For instance, one might wish to customize their own named keymap to their liking, but still preserve the original "Blender" keymap in order to switch back to it quickly and at will.
EDIT: "this is confirmed and open issue. Since there are bunch of reports for this in linked here, I would call this a bug". This was the devs answer in the blender project support website.

This doesn't sound like a normal behavior to me. I advise using the menu Help > Report a bug, and see what the devs say about it, and also post the bug report link here in the comments. In the meantime, I close the question, since bugs are out of topic on this website. IF the devs say it isn't a bug, please [edit] your question to give more details and it will queue your question for reopening.
